# How to save star rating results form the jQuery star rating plugin + codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am working on ecommerce application. User can rate the products and product ratings should be calculated by every single click of the user.I want to save the star rating results from the jquery and it should be stored in database. Is there any possible ways to store?

Controller code:

```
function rating()
    {
        $rating_value = $this->input->post("rate_val", true);
        $designId = $this->input->post("id", true);
        $user = $this->model_name->getUser($this->session->userdata('user_name')); //session user details
        $rating_date = date("Y-m-d");

        if ($user['id'])   //logged in user id
        {
            if (!$this->model_name->is_design_rated($designId , $user['id']))
            {
                if ($this->model_name->insert_rating($designId, $user['id'], $rating_value, $rating_date))
                {
                    echo json_encode(array("code" => "Success", "msg" => "Your Design Rating has been posted"));
                }
                else
                {
                    echo json_encode(array("code" => "Error", "msg" => "There was a problem rating your design"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo json_encode(array("code" => "Error", "msg" => "You have already rated this design"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(array("code" => "Error", "msg" => "You have to login to rate the design"));
        }
        exit(0);
    }
```

View file:

```
<p id="msg_rate"></p>

<input type="hidden" name="hidden_design_id" id="hidden_design_id" value="<?php echo $designId;?>"/>

  <?php 
        if (!$this->usermodel->isUserMember()) //Check if user logged in
        {
            $radio_level = "disabled";
        }
        else
        {
            $radio_level = " ";
        }

        for($i = 1;$i <= 5;$i++)
        {
            if ($i == round($avgVotes['rating_value']))
            {
           ?>
                <input class="auto-submit-star" type="radio" name="rating" <?php echo "$radio_level";?> value="<?php echo $i;?>" checked="checked"/>
           <?php
            }
            else
            {
           ?>
               <input class="auto-submit-star" type="radio" name="rating" <?php echo "$radio_level";?> value="<?php echo $i;?>"/>
           <?php
            }
        } //end of for
    ?>
```

Js code:

```
$('.auto-submit-star').rating({
               required: true,
               callback: function(value, link) {

                $.ajax({
                         type: "post",
                         url: baseurl + "designs/rating",
                         dataType: "json",
                         data: { id: $("#hidden_design_id").val(), rate_val: value } ,

                  success: function(e) {
                       //$.jGrowl(e.code + "
" + e.msg);
                             //alert(e.code + "
" + e.msg);
                             $('#msg_rate').html(e.msg);
                             $('#msg_rate').fadeIn();
                             $('#msg_rate').fadeOut(5000);
                             window.location.reload();
                   }
             });
         }
    });
```

Comment: is your rating star coming now?

Comment: i guess within <p id="msg_rate"></p>,your raty is coming...right?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
$("#msg_rate").raty({ 
    half: true,
    score: function() {

    },
    click: function(score, evt) {      
      $.ajax({
           type     : 'POST',
           url      : base_url+'controller_name/function_name',
           data     : {'id':$("#hidden_design_id").val(), 'rate_val':score},
           success  : function(resp){
                //alert(resp);
                if(resp == "1"){
                    alert("successfull");  
                }else{
                    alert("not successfull");
                }

           },
           error: function(resp){
                alert("error");
           }  
        });              
      }
});
```

please let me know if you face any problem

Comment: Okay thanks for your valuable info Aritra. Let u know once i have done.